# jQuery Mobile - binding to pageinit event

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-init

I am trying to understand the following [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/events.html) example.

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

What is `#aboutPage` in this context?  What is the object `pageinit` is binding to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`aboutPage` should be the id of the page.(i.e.div with `data-role="page"`).`live()` attaches the funcion you have defined which contains the`alert` to the `pageinit` event of `aboutPage`.`pageinit` is triggered on a page when the page is initialized.

So in short What your code does is

> it will execute the alert statement when `aboutPage` is initialized

The page might be initialized even if it is not in view.So even before you go to that page,the `pageinit` of the div will be triggered.If you are loading another html file as the new page `pageinit` for that page will be triggered only when you load that page into view.So,in your case if you want to do something when your div comes into view,you can try the `pagebeforeshow` and `pageshow`.`pagebeforeshow` will be triggered on the new page before animation starts and `pageshow` after animation is over.

Comment: Yup. That is what I guessed it would be and I tried hooking up pageinit event on div with data-role="page" but for some reason the method is not getting called the first time I transition to a page. When I hit refresh the method gets called.

Comment: Edited the answer to explain about this.Hope it helps.

Comment: Figured it out. Every page had it's own javascript to hook up 'pageshow' events. However I was using  $.mobile.changePage which only loads a div with data-role=page and nothing else on that page (including inline javascript) gets executed. Here is the answer that helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449402/jquery-mobile-mobile-changepage-not-loading-external-js-files/7449731#7449731