# Jquery Mobile .click does not work

Tags: jquery, mobile, click, live

I'm creating a mobile site for a client and I need to create a function to show and hide a DIV element when a button(a tag) is pressed.
This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#wrapper').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  $("#btnInfo").click(function(){
      $("#pageInfo").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

What happens is:
When the page loads and i press btnInfo, the div shows up, works like it should but then i press on a link to go to the next page but on that page it does not show up anymore, whenever when i go back to the page i loaded at first it still works.
I think this is because the page is loaded in AJAX, which i want it to be. I searched for a fix and i found: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html and [jQuery Mobile - binding to pageinit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729729/jquery-mobile-binding-to-pageinit-event) tried it both, and the alert shows up when i switch pages but the function i wrote does not work

what do i do wrong?

Greetings,
Harm.

Answer (score 3):

The click method needs to be attached via [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to the element that is being appended on-the-fly.

```
$("#btnInfo").on('click', function() {
    $("#pageInfo").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I answered this before `on()` existed in the API. I've updated my answer, but I see Saurabh already got there. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#btnInfo" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
          $("#pageInfo").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#btnInfo").bind('click',function(){
          $("#pageInfo").toggle();
      });
```

Comment: Tried that, and it didnt work... Thanks for your help though.
Code: 
$('#wrapper').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  $("#btnInfo").bind('click',function(){
       $("#pageInfo").toggle();
    });
});