# Bind('pageinit') fails to call method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind a page initialize event from, afaik, jquerymobile, to a method so I can set my header, this is done, because later I wish to set it dynamically.
But my event doesn't even trigger :'-(
Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('#mapmode').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    initPageHeader();
});

function initPageHeader(){
    alert('oldhtml');
    var oldhtml=document.getElementById('header').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML="";
    var html = oldthml + '<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" ><img'+
    ' align="middle"src="../images/back.png" alt="back" vspace="2"/></a><h1>'+
    '<img align="middle"src="../images/main_header.png" alt="logo" vspace="2"/>'+
    '</h1><a href="#first" data-role="button" data-inline="true">'+
    '<img align="middle"src="../images/home.png" '+
    'alt="picture to take you to the first page"/></a>'
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML=html;
}
```

Comment: The `alert(oldhtml)` is before `var oldhtml`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729729/jquery-mobile-binding-to-pageinit-event

Comment: Thanks inkbug, wasn't the problem though :) changed it to 'oldhtml'. still doesn't trigger, but lots of ideas below. Digging in to them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to `pageinit` instead of using event delegation, you have to do that on the document itself:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(event) {
    initPageHeader();
});
```

If this behavior is specific to the `#mapmode` page, then event delegation is the way to go:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mapmode", function(event) {
    initPageHeader();
});
```

In passing, proper use of jQuery can make your event handler shorter and more readable:

```
function initPageHeader()
{
    $("#header").html(function(index, originalMarkup) {
        return originalMarkup
            + '<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">'
            + '<img align="middle" src="../images/back.png" alt="back" '
            + 'vspace="2"/></a><h1><img align="middle" '
            + 'src="../images/main_header.png" alt="logo" vspace="2"/>'
            + '</h1><a href="#first" data-role="button" data-inline="true">'
            + '<img align="middle"src="../images/home.png" '
            + 'alt="picture to take you to the first page"/></a>';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats the incorrect use of on for a bind isn't it? `$(document)` is used to replace the `.live()` functionality.

Comment: @Jeemusu, the code that was in your comment was equivalent to `bind()`, not `delegate()` or `live()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296530/jquery-onclick-vs-click-and-delegateclick.

Comment: Does this override normal launch functionality of my page? because now it only launches this method and does nothing else?

Comment: @Anders, it should not override any other `pageinit` handlers. The first code snippet in my answer will run for every page, the second one will run only when `#mapmode` is initialized.

Comment: Awesome last function :D Thanks!

Btw you know if there is any way to set a maxheight on pageheader, and squeeze the images to fit?

Comment: @Anders, thanks :) Your `max-height` issue is not really related and would warrant another question IMHO (I don't have an instant answer handy for that one).

Comment: Hmm seems like your initpageheader function doesn't raelly work :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13841/discussion-between-anders-metnik-and-frederic-hamidi)

Comment: Ahh forgot the return statement after removing originalmarkup, :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `alert(oldhtml);` before you set it. Move it above your `document.getElementById('header').innerHTML=html;`

As suggested by jeemusu below you can find out more about [jQuery .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as bind is being deprecated.

Comment: Also bind is also depreciated. Try using `.on()` instead.