# Jquery mobile: pageinit event not fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can somebody out there help me out with this code  please? This might be something stupid to fix but I've been now stuck with this since hours!
pageinit event doesn't fire. The only way to get it fired is to move the script inisde the body, just before the closing tag, but this weird structure I haven't found in any official documentation, and I suspect is wrong !
I am testing on Samsung phone emulator (avd).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $( document ).delegate("#aboutPage", "pageinit", function () {
                alert('ok');
            alert($('#homePage').text());
        });

</script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test Mobile Application</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
      <p>-....</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Begin Homepage -->
    <section id="homePage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
      <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content" data-role="content">
        <p>Homepage</p>
        <a onclick="javascript:alert($('#homePage').text());" data-role="button">aaaaa</a>
        <p>
          <a href="#aboutPage">Go to About Page</a>
        </p>
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
      </div>
      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <!-- End Homepage -->
    <!-- Begin About Page -->
    <section id="aboutPage" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
      <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content" data-role="content">
        <p>This is About Page</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#portfolioPage">Go to Portfolio Page</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <!-- End About page -->
    <!-- Begin Portfolio Page -->
    <section id="portfolioPage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
      <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content" data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        <p>This is Portfolio Page</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#homePage">Go back to Homepage</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </footer>
    </section>
    <!-- End Portfolio page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729729/jquery-mobile-binding-to-pageinit-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your code works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/CCght/).  `pageinit()` is being called exactly once when your About page is being fetched either by clicking on `aaaa` button or by link `Go to About Page`.

Couple of things though:

**First** Link `jquery.mobile` first then use it

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Your code as of right now
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Your code goes here
</script>
```

**Second** Since you're using jquery 1.8.2 you may consider switch from `delegate()` to `on()`

```
   $(document).on("pageinit", "#aboutPage", function () {
        alert('ok');
        alert($('#homePage').text());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peterm. It worked. I don't know what I was doing before! I should stop writing code so late at night! Bye, Janko.

Comment: I definitely would, but here it's saying "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" .. sorry I am new! I will as soon as I got them.

Answer (score 0):

After some big search I found that the pageinit event doesn't fired due Ajax. Then in the link where you call next page add data-ajax="false" 
Second Page