# Script does not run in JQuery Mobile 1.2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a script in a separate js file, which for now, contains

```
$('#page-seriesLevel').live('pageinit', function(){
   console.log(document.URL + ' loaded.');});
```

This is called from series.php ideally when the page is ready, and catalog.php links to series.php.

But when I go to that page from catalog.php, the script does not execute. I have to refresh to see it. Sometimes the script executes from catalog.php which it shouldn't.

Comment: Check this similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729729/jquery-mobile-binding-to-pageinit-event)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729729/jquery-mobile-binding-to-pageinit-event]

Comment: If it is not a problem, mail me your pages and js file and I will fix it for you?

Comment: Thanks for that link Bertrand, and the help offer Gajotres. I was able to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that JQM loads pages via ajax, but I didn't know that it just loads the element with `data-role="page"`, ignoring the head (where my JS was), as this answer says. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449731/677331

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what your asking.  If the problem is that the page load event, 'pageinit', is not triggered every time you go to the page, try using 'pagebeforeshow' or 'pageshow'.  'pageinit' is only triggered the first time you go to the page.

See the "page load events" section on http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html for more information.