# jQuery mobile loading when it shouldn't, even with ajaxEnabled set to false

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605093/jquery-mobile-loads-a-page-into-dom-even-when-i-dont-ask-it-to) where jQuery mobile loads into DOM. However, in that case, ajax loading was enabled and he was using `window.location` to move across pages.

I am not using `window.location`, just normal hyperlinks, and I have turned off ajax loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // disable page transitions
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    }
```

Nonetheless, if I:

1. Start on page A
2. Click a link to page B
3. Click the back button on my Android phone
4. Click a link to page C

The following happens:

1. Page C loads in its entirety, including all JavaScript and media
2. The [loading...] graphic appears
3. The content of page A loads into the page

This is not reliable; sometimes the content is from an even earlier page.

Note that in step 3, clicking the jQuery mobile-generated back button results in the same behavior.

Note that this even happens for links which are explicitly marked as `data-ajax="false"`.

Also, this does **not** occur on desktop browsers, only Android (and it also appears to happen in the iPhone, although I've only tested it via the simulator).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was caused by pushState.

From the [official documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html):

> **Important: rel="external" and $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false**
>
> Slightly different implementations of the replaceState API in various
>   browsers can cause odd behavior in specific scenarios. For example,
>   some browser implementations (including desktop browsers) implement
>   the **`popstate`** event differently when linking externally and moving back
>   to a page onto which state has already been pushed/replaced. When
>   building a jQuery Mobile application where the ajax navigation is
>   being explicitly disabled, either through the frequent use of
>   `rel="external"` on links or by disabling Ajax navigation completely via
>   the `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false`, we recommend disabling the pushState
>   feature to fall back to the hash based navigation for more consistent
>   behavior.

All it took was adding code to disable pushState in the header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
</script>
```

Now it works!